# vqmod generate cache for all files

Tags: opencart

Is it possible to generate all of the vqcache files for vqmod at once?

I would like to run this script once when the server has a low load and it would go through all of the qmod files and apply all of the changes, ready and waiting for the high load.

This would also alert me of any vqmod errors, instead of having to wait for them to occur.

E,g when I install/uninstall the extension I also need to uninstall the vqmod extensions with:

```
/**
 * install/uninstall vqmod files for extension
 *
 * @param string $action = install/uninstall
 */
private function _vqmodAction($action){

    $vqmod_path = str_replace("system", "vqmod", DIR_SYSTEM);

    // Clear vqmod cache
    $files = glob($vqmod_path.'vqcache/vq*');
    if ($files) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                @unlink($file);
                clearstatcache();
            }
        }
    }

    // Force vqmod to re-generate cache
    global $vqmod;
    $vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

    // Re-name vqmod files
    $vqmod_xml_path = $vqmod_path . "xml/";
    $vqmod_files = array('file', 'file_languages', 'file_admin');
    foreach($vqmod_files as $filename){
        if($action == "uninstall"){
            $from = '.xml';
            $to = '.xml_';
        } else {
            $from = '.xml_';
            $to = '.xml';
        }
        if (file_exists($vqmod_xml_path.$filename.$from)) {
            rename($vqmod_xml_path.$filename.$from, $vqmod_xml_path.$filename.$to);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The reason for modCheck the startup.php is because this includes required files and changes made via vqmod. Is this the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this manually with an external program like httrack . When you crawly your site with a similar application all pages will be visited before your site visitors do. So all cache files will be created.

> http://www.httrack.com/

Do you need to repeat this occasionally ? If so you need to make a self crawling / or cache maker script.

Answer (score 7):

vQmod simply requires you to delete the `/vqmod/mods.cache` file in the latest version to get it to refresh. It will also regenerate with the files being renamed/removed/added too in the latest versions (2.3.X + ) so unless you have older versions, this isn't a problem. Erdinç Çorbacı is correct for the httrack tool with one exception - it won't generate vqcache files for any admin pages unless it's logged into the admin area. Of course, just deleting the `/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-*` files and the `/vqmod/mods.cache` (if it exists) is enough to force the regeneration

Comment: +1 for pointing admin page issue . Yes httrack cand navigate to all admin pages even though you login somehow (bco Ajax things)... But i guess there is no need to cache admin pages.

Comment: So you need to delete at least the vq2-* file(s) manually no matter what if you want to say - remove mod and see the results immediately? It seemed like just deleting the XML file didn't always do the trick immediately.

Comment: @MikeiLL - No, if you're using version 2.3 or above they will regenerate automatically

Comment: @JayGilford I don't think this forces regeneration, it still needs to wait to be poked before it gens a new cache. Just tried it on a test site with 0 traffic in a case where it was to mod a helper class (never directly used outside of other classes). Never will gen the mod on that file since it's bootstrapped and "never accessed" directly. Is there a way to force it to run through all the mods at once, without waiting to be provoked to do so?

Comment: @dhaupin - unless theres something wrong with your server, then yes it will. I know this, as I coded it ;-)

Comment: @JayGilford Aye i thought it did too. Tried with 4 ver of php, liquidweb cent6.6, digitalocean cent7, work intranet, wamp local, OC 1.5x & 2x, reinstalling with both 2.5x and 2.4x branches. If there is no "request schema", it won't generate it. Close the tab out on a dev store that gets 0 traffic, go to FTP, delete the cache and mods.cache, then wait for them to populate again. Or, try modding a bootstrap class that never really "sees a request" such as registering a mods cache whitelist URI in this file https://github.com/budgetneon/pagecache/blob/master/upload/system/library/pagecache.php

Comment: @dhaupin - Do you mean you expect it to generate all of the files automatically without any pages being loaded? If that's the case then no it doesn't do that. VQMod generates files as they are needed, unless the cache file exists. It does this by hooking into where requires/includes are called and gets the file name there. What my answer is referring to is deleting mods.cache forces the vqcache files to be created again, even if they exist. It doesn't delete them and regenerate at that exact moment - it simply ensures that the cache files don't remain stale

Comment: @JayGilford Aye man, it works good as it is, but per the question he (and I) are trying to figure a method to force gen all the operations at once, even if cached already and/or the target files are never accessed directly. Heck if that worked, might as well have an option to run in "manual mode" where it only gen operations when you want it to. Would be great for querying jobs up from multiple devs or on stores with hundreds of mods. You dont want to repeatedly gen hundreds of mods under load. Strange fatals everywhere, traffic redirected to homepage, and other weird stuff for like 10 secs.

Comment: @dhaupin - I understand, but as there are the wildcards to consider in paths, it gets very tricky generating them all. There is no way to do this currently

Comment: @JayGilford true true, would be very hard. I looked at it the other day and didn't see much I could do short of reinventing a wheel. Its one of those things like cake and eating it too hah. Personally, I really just want to be able to mod helper classes, ie that pagecache register url and some others floating around out there. Have yet to figure out how to poke it enough to trigger the gen operation. Appreciate your time and work in it regardless, its a great system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to reply directly to @dhaupin's comment, hopefully they'll see this.

I ran into a similar problem, described here: https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/issues/51

..and came up with this quick/dirty/hacky solution that seems to work: https://gist.github.com/jktoole/be9fdee2263b48194d07

You could probably mod the PHP bit into something that would help solve your problem.